# Как использовать jqvmap в ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Хочу использовать в проекте  [данное дополнение](https://github.com/manifestinteractive/jqvmap). Однако я не совсем понимаю, как его переделать под концепцию React'a. Подскажите пожалуйста как это следует сделать, или возможно есть какой-то туториал по этой теме?

Comment: Я не вникал в чем конкретно дополнение, но смысл такой: Вы не должны манипулировать dom который наворотил реакт. Но создать в реакте пустой див скажем с каким-нибудь классом, а потом после того как компонент замаунтился внутрь этого дива понапихивать дом сгенеренный жукверями - это норм (но ворнинги будут правда скорее всего).

Comment: А вот если вы хотите эту штуку под реакт переписать - ну вперед, лучший туториал - официальная дока реакта.

Comment: Я не хочу ничего переписывать. Я хочу интегрировать ее в проект,чтобы можно было ее использовать(ставить метки и сохранять данные о них)

Comment: "Переделать его под концепцию реакта" - это переписать. Птмчт jquery - это прямые dom манипуляции, а реакт - манипуляции своим виртуальным домом. Подход при котором это иногда можно состыковать - я описал в первом комментарии.

Comment: В любом случае это некоторое количество ручной работы и подточки конкретно под ваше приложение, волшебные пару строчек - писать вам. Операции по совмещению ужа с ежом обычно достаточно уникальны для двух конкретных особей.